# Decimal to Floating Point 9-bit

Tags: floating-point

how do you convert 106 decimal to 9-bit floating point where the msb is the sign with a 4-bit exponent and 4-bit mantissa? Is it possible?

Comment: In order to formulate an answer, it would be useful to know whether this floating-point format follows the conventions used for IEEE-754 binary floating-point formats. In particular, does it use a biased exponent, with the exponent value 0 reserved for zeros and denormals, and the exponent value 0xF (i.e. decimal 15) reserved for infinities and NaN?

Comment: "IEEE 754" by itself isn't really enough, since IEEE 754 doesn't specify a 9-bit format. We still need to know what the exponent bias is, for example. (Based on the IEEE 754 formats that do exist, I'd *guess* an exponent bias of 7, but this is a guess.) If you have example values with corresponding bit patterns, that would help with understanding the format.

Comment: Ah ok. Yep 7 bias. I'm pretty sure njuffa made the right assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comment by OP, the floating-point format in question follows IEEE-754 conventions, so it uses a mantissa representation with implicit integer bit, and a biased exponent with the smallest exponent encoding reserved for zeros and denormals and the largest exponent encoding reserved for infinities and NaNs.

106 (decimal) = 1.10101 * 2<sup>6</sup> (binary). In the proposed IEEE-style nine-bit floating-point format, the exponent bias is 7. The magnitude of normalized operands is 2<sup>-6</sup> ≦ |x| < 2<sup>8</sup>. Therefore, 106 is within representable range since 2<sup>8</sup> = 256.

However, 106 is not representable *exactly* since it requires five fractional mantissa bits, while only four are provided by the proposed format. The closest representable number, using rounding to nearest-or-even, is 1.1010 * 2<sup>6</sup> = 104. The binary encoding of that is 0_1101_1010.

Comment: I think you want 2^8=256 (so `106` *is* within the representable range, though not actually representable before rounding). And 106 is `1.10101 * 2^6`, rather than `1.10101 * 2^8`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: You are absolutely right, not sure how I got that wrong, other than that I posted before the first cup of coffee. I'll fix this right away.

Comment: Yes, apologies for the nitpicking on an otherwise excellent answer.  (I already upvoted.)

Comment: @MarkDickinson I do not consider this nitpicking at all, attention to detail is super important with questions like this. So thank you again for bringing it to my attention. I would have been embarrassed if the incorrect answer had been up there for a prolonged period of time.